# What is the font used in this Hatfield & McCoy Moonshine logo?

Tags: font-identification, serif

I am trying to figure out what font is used in the below Moonshine Logo. I am only interested in the font used for “Hatfield & McCoy”, not “Drink of the Devil” or “Moonshine”.

[image]
[image]
[image]

There are more samples of the font, including the image posted, [on their website](https://www.drinkofthedevilmoonshine.com/) (where it says: “AUTHENTIC MOONSHINE BROUGHT TO YOU BY THE NOTORIOUS …”)

I have tried all font-identification websites and I can’t get anything close. It looks like the original designer may have also sheared the text so I tried straightening it out as well. Still no result on WhatTheFont or What Font Is.

This font is a retro style serif font with some swashes. This is most likely a small-caps font where the large caps are the only ones with the swashes.